# How to change "OsMuiLanguages" in windows-11?

Tags: windows, powershell, locale

**Background**:
In an attempt to change language settings for a `Windows-11 Home` edition, from ES to US.
I managed to get most changes done, but still there are several other *items** returning Spanish items, or aliases.

The only place left that is still showing `es-ES` (Spanish) shows up as `OsMuiLanguages`:

```
# Get-computerinfo | FL OsLanguage,OSMUIlanguages, OsLocale

OsLanguage     : en-US
OsMuiLanguages : {en-US, es-ES}
OsLocale       : en-US
```

Example of another item returning Spanish:

```
# Get-LocalGroup

Name                                 Description
----                                 -----------
Administradores                      Los administradores tienen acceso completo y sin
Device Owners                        Los miembros de este grupo pueden cambiar la …
Hyper-V Administrators               Members of this group have complete and unrestricted …
IIS_IUSRS                            Grupo integrado usado por Internet Information Services.
Invitados                            De forma predeterminada, los invitados tienen el mismo… 
...

# net localgroup

Aliases for \\LAPTOP-xxxx

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*Administradores
*Device Owners
*Hyper-V Administrators
*IIS_IUSRS
*Invitados
*Lectores del registro de eventos
*System Managed Accounts Group
*Usuarios
*Usuarios COM distribuidos
*Usuarios de administración remota
*Usuarios del monitor de sistema
*Usuarios del registro de rendimiento

The command completed successfully.
```

UPDATE: 2023-11-28

Adding some additional output:

```
# dism /online /get-intl

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.22621.1

Image Version: 10.0.22621.2715

Reporting online international settings.

Default system UI language : en-US
System locale : en-US
Default time zone : Romance Standard Time
Active keyboard(s) : 0409:00000409, 0c0a:0000040a
Keyboard layered driver : Not installed.

Installed language(s): en-US
  Type : Fully localized language.
Installed language(s): es-ES
  Type : Partially localized language, MUI type.
  Fallback Languages en-US

The operation completed successfully.

#--------------------------------------
# whoami /groups /FO TABLE

Group Name                                                    Type             SID          Attributes
============================================================= ================ ============ ===============================================================
Everyone                                                      Well-known group S-1-1-0      Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
NT AUTHORITY\Local account and member of Administrators group Well-known group S-1-5-114    Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
BUILTIN\Administradores                                       Alias            S-1-5-32-544 Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group, Group owner
BUILTIN\Usuarios                                              Alias            S-1-5-32-545 Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE                                      Well-known group S-1-5-4      Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
CONSOLE LOGON                                                 Well-known group S-1-2-1      Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users                              Well-known group S-1-5-11     Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
NT AUTHORITY\This Organization                                Well-known group S-1-5-15     Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
NT AUTHORITY\Local account                                    Well-known group S-1-5-113    Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
LOCAL                                                         Well-known group S-1-2-0      Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
NT AUTHORITY\NTLM Authentication                              Well-known group S-1-5-64-10  Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
Mandatory Label\High Mandatory Level                          Label            S-1-16-12288
```

Note that there are different `Type`s shown here, such as `Alias` and `Label`, for which I cannot find any info.

---

Q: **Where is `OsMuiLanguages` set, and how can I remove it?**

<sub>`Bonus Question`:

*Would it remove the ES language from other items above?*</sub>

Comment: most language settings don't take effect until after a reboot. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining the - terse - [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ComputerInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.computerinfo.oslanguage) documentation (the return type of the [`Get-ComputerInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-computerinfo) cmdlet) with observed behavior:

- `OsMuiLanguages` is the list of locally installed *language packs* (Multilingual User Interface (MUI) Packs, though some may actually of type LIP (Language Interface Pack)), including the one that the OS shipped with, the so-called *install language*; the order in which the languages are listed does *not* indicate which language is the active Windows display language (see below); instead, it seems that the install language is listed *first*, followed by the languages installed later in alphabetical order.

  - You can manage and download additional languages via the Settings app (downloadable languages are now called LXPs, *Local eXperience Packs*, and their ultimate source is Microsoft Store); you can directly launch the relevant page as follows:

    ```bash
    Start-Process ms-settings:regionformatting
    ```
- `OsLanguage` is the so-called *install language*, i.e. the language that the OS shipped with.
- `OsLocale` is the legacy *system locale* aka *language for non-Unicode programs*, which determines the culture-specific OEM and ANSI *code pages* used by non-Unicode applications. Notably, the OEM code page is still invariably used in consoles.

I assume that it is only possible to **remove language packs** that were installed later (i.e. that you cannot remove the *install* language) and only if they're not used as the current *system UI language* (the language used by the Welcome screen and system accounts, as well as by default for *future users*), namely via [`Remove-AppxPackage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/appx/remove-appxpackage) in combination with [`Set-WinUserLanguageList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/international/set-winuserlanguagelist), in order to remove the language from the list of preferred languages too; e.g., for `es-ES`:

```bash
# The language's tag, as reported in the .OSMuiLanguages property.
$langTag = 'es-ES'

# Remove -WhatIf to perform actual removal.
Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.LanguageExperiencePack$langTag |
  Remove-AppxPackage -WhatIf

# Prompts for confirmation; add -Force to skip the prompt.
Set-WinUserLanguageList (
  (Get-WinUserLanguageList) | Where-Object LanguageTag -ne $langTag
)
```

Note:

- These operations affect the *current user only*.
- If you start an elevated session and add `-AllUsers` to *both* `Get-AppxPackage` and `Remove-AppxPackage`, you can remove packages even for other users, but note that the `Set-WinUserLanguageList` call (or its interactive equivalent of removing the uninstalled language from the list of user languages in the Settings app) must be made *from each user account*, though with additional effort you could perform this centrally as well, by programmatically loading the registry hives of all users and performing the following in each, if present:

  - Remove the tag of the language to remove (e.g, `es-ES`) from the `REG_MULTI_SZ` *value* named `Languages` from key
    `Control Panel\International\User Profile`
  - Remove a *subkey* named for the language tag, if present.

---

However, perhaps all you're looking for is to **change the active *Windows display language* for the *current user***:

To *get* the active display language:

```bash
if ($result = Get-WinUILanguageOverride) { $result } else { (Get-WinUserLanguageList)[0] }
```

To *set* it, there are two options:

- *Re-order* the list of user languages, to make sure that the desired language comes first; e.g., if you haven't removed the `es-ES` language pack, you can put it *last* in the list of languages:

  ```bash
  $langTag = 'es-ES'

  # Prompts for confirmation; add -Force to skip the prompt.
  Set-WinUserLanguageList (
    @((Get-WinUserLanguageList) | Where-Object LanguageTag -ne $langTag) + $langTag
  )
  ```

  - This list of language tags is stored in a `REG_MULTI_SZ` registry value named `Languages` in key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International\User Profile`.
- Put an *override* in place; this leaves the list of languages as-is (whose ordering implies language preference for applications downloaded from Microsoft Store):

  ```bash
  Set-WinUILanguageOverride en-US
  ```

  - This setting is stored in a `REG_SZ` registry value named `WindowsOverride` in key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International\User Profile`.
- Log off and back on or reboot for the change to take effect.

The above:

- makes GUI elements appear in that language (if available)
- makes `cmd.exe` and certain standard utilities (e.g. `net.exe` and `whoami.exe`) print messages in that language
- sets the *UI* culture in .NET / PowerShell to that language, as reflected in `[cultureinfo]::CurrentUICulture` and [`Get-UICulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-uiculture).

  - *Windows PowerShell* then uses that language in its messages and error messages.
  - By contrast, [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) does *not*, because it hasn't been internationalized - see [GitHub issue #666](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/666).

**Note**:

- It seems that **certain language-specific information is created *statically* based on the *original* display language, which is therefore *retained*** even after switching to a different display language later.
- Notably, as you've discovered and show in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77548989/45375), this **applies to the *names* and *descriptions* of *built-in* user and group accounts such as `Administrators`**; [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77567895/45375) shows a programmatic way to rename them after the fact.

**Additional considerations:**

- Changing the display language *may not* also set the *regional settings* (number, time, ... formats) as reflected in `[cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture]` and `Get-Culture` / `$PSCulture`: Only if the `Regional format` setting in the Settings app shows `Recommended` (which corresponds to the `UserLocaleFromLanguageProfileOptOut` `REG_SZ` registry value in key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International\User Profile` either not existing or having a value of `0`) are the regional settings automatically changed in tandem with the display language.

  - If needed, as an alternative to changing the setting interactively via the Settings app (`Start-Process ms-settings:regionformatting`), you can use [`Set-Culture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//hh852137(v=technet.10)) (note that there is *no* <del>`Set-UICulture`</del>), but the latter only allows you to specify a new regional settings *statically*, whereas the former allows you to return the setting to `Recommended`, which keeps the regional setting synced with future changes to the display language.
- To change the *system locale* (code pages for non-Unicode programs and consoles), run `intl.cpl` to open the relevant Control Panel applet, switch to the `Administrative` tab and click on `Change system locale...` (requires elevation and a reboot). As the name suggests, this is a *system-wide* setting and therefore affects *all* users.

  - Note: Windows 10 introduced the option to set both the ANSI and OEM legacy code pages to UTF-8 (`65001`), which potentially enables full Unicode support even for legacy and console applications; however, as of Windows 11 22H2, the feature is still labeled *beta* and it has *far-reaching consequences* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375) for details.
- By default, the *keyboard* language is determined by the first language shown in the list of preferred languages in the relevant Settings app page (`Start-Process ms-settings:regionformatting`), also reflected in the first one output by [`Get-WinUserLanguageList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/international/get-winuserlanguagelist).

  - You can alternatively pick a fixed keyboard language via the advanced keyboard settings: Run `Start-Process ms-settings:typing` and click on `Advanced keyboard settings`.
- You may also want to change the display language for the Welcome (logon) screen and *future user accounts*.

  - Run `intl.cpl` to open the relevant Control Panel applet, switch to the `Administrative` tab and click on `Copy settings...` (requires elevation).

See also:

- [Manage the input and display language settings in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/manage-the-input-and-display-language-settings-in-windows-12a10cb4-8626-9b77-0ccb-5013e0c7c7a2#input_language) (*GUI*-based methods).

Comment: Hi. I tried `Set-WinUILanguageOverride en-US`, which indeed was empty at first. Rebooted, but no change from what I had before. It seem that although the language for the binaries is presented in `en-US`, the user group *names* and their *Descriptions* are still the same in `es-ES`. **1.** I guess once they have been created, they can never be changed again, regardless what you do? **2.** The results from `net localgroup` show the text: `Aliases for \\LAPTOP-xxxx`, what does that mean? Where are these aliases defined?

Comment: From my understanding, user *groups* are really using SID's, so why doesn't a *language change*, change these as well?

Comment: Another thing that is not clear, are the different (group) `Type`s, as mentioned in the groups tables from `whoami /groups /FO TABLE`.

Comment: @not2qubit, yes, it does look like the _descriptions_ of user and group accounts are created _once, statically_, so a subsequent display-language change has no effect. However, you can change the descriptions via `lusrmgr.msc` or, for groups, via `net localgroup <name> /comment:<new-descriptions`, from an elevated session.

Comment: @not2qubit, as for the _aliases_ used for the built-in groups, as shown by `net localgroup`: It looks like they too are statically defined - but I don't know where.

Comment: @not2qubit, as for the `Type` and `Attribute` columns in the output of `whoami /groups /FO TABLE`: these do seem to be _dynamically_ generated values to describe each group's type and attributes using the active display language.

Comment: Thanks for accepting, @not2qubit. I've added more information re keyboard languages and code for removal of a language pack. I'm puzzled, though: Unless my description is wrong, your `Get-ComputerInfo` output suggest that the OS's _install language_ was English, not Spanish - though a Spanish language pack may have been preinstalled and the user opted for Spanish _during installation_. Is that what happened?

Comment: I don't recall exactly how things went, but AFAICR when I first started PC for first time, the setup process was all in Spanish. At that point I selected everything I could in English. After that, some things was in English and Spanish, so I went through the hoops of finding & setting everything I could (like you suggested above) to English. At one point I found a command to an applet to change language packs. Default was ES, with EN as *backup* option. But I could not change this to EN as default, but managed to change it by registry hack, in hope that OS would update the language pack.

Comment: It was `lpksetup.exe /u`. It doesn'l allow you to change the default. So I changed the registry as described [here](https://superuser.com/a/1662219/116221). But it didn't really make any difference as I first thought.

Comment: Thanks, @not2qubit. `lpksetup.exe /u` only seems to work with old-style language packs, not with the modern, Microsoft Store-backed LXPs (Language eXperience package). For the latter, you need `Remove-AppxPackage`, as (now) shown in the answer. Neither `lpksetup.exe /u` nor `Remove-AppxPackage` alone also remove a package from the list of the user's (preferred) languages. None of that helps the fundamental problem, as we've discovered: built-in local groups _statically_ receive localized names and descriptions when a language other then English is chosen during _initial setup_ of the OS.

Comment: @not2qubit: As for the terminology in the `Type` column of `whoami /groups` output: I've added a new bottom section to the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77567895/45375).