# How to Remove foreign user group aliases in Windows-11?

Tags: windows, user-interface, active-directory, account

**Background**:
In an attempt to change language settings for a `Windows-11 Home` edition, from ES to US.
I managed to get most changes done, but there are still several other *items** returning in Spanish.

One Example returning Spanish groups:

```
Get-LocalGroup

Name                                 Description
----                                 -----------
Administradores                      Los administradores tienen acceso completo y sin
Device Owners                        Los miembros de este grupo pueden cambiar la …
Hyper-V Administrators               Members of this group have complete and unrestricted …
IIS_IUSRS                            Grupo integrado usado por Internet Information Services.
Invitados                            De forma predeterminada, los invitados tienen el mismo… 
...
```

Looking further how/why these groups are in Spanish, I ran `whoami /groups` and `net localgroup`.  There I got the following output showing that some groups are listed as **`Alias`** under the `Type` column.

```
# whoami /groups

Group Name                                                    Type             SID          Attributes
============================================================= ================ ============ ===============================================================
Everyone                                                      Well-known group S-1-1-0      Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
NT AUTHORITY\Local account and member of Administrators group Well-known group S-1-5-114    Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
BUILTIN\Administradores                                       Alias            S-1-5-32-544 Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group, Group owner
BUILTIN\Usuarios                                              Alias            S-1-5-32-545 Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE                                      Well-known group S-1-5-4      Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
CONSOLE LOGON                                                 Well-known group S-1-2-1      Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users                              Well-known group S-1-5-11     Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
NT AUTHORITY\This Organization                                Well-known group S-1-5-15     Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
NT AUTHORITY\Local account                                    Well-known group S-1-5-113    Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
LOCAL                                                         Well-known group S-1-2-0      Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
NT AUTHORITY\NTLM Authentication                              Well-known group S-1-5-64-10  Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
Mandatory Label\High Mandatory Level                          Label            S-1-16-12288


# net localgroup

Aliases for \\LAPTOP-xxxx

------------------------------------------
*Administradores
*Device Owners
*Hyper-V Administrators
*IIS_IUSRS
*Invitados
*Lectores del registro de eventos
*System Managed Accounts Group
*Usuarios
*Usuarios COM distribuidos
*Usuarios de administración remota
*Usuarios del monitor de sistema
*Usuarios del registro de rendimiento

The command completed successfully.
```

---

Q: **How to remove these group aliases and see the original group names?**

<sub>`Bonus Question`:

*Would it remove the ES language from those same items?*</sub>

---

Related Question:

- [How to change "OsMuiLanguages" in windows-11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77548908/how-to-change-osmuilanguages-in-windows-11) (my own)

Comment: As far as I remember you can't change these things in a language-specific version of Windows. The only solution is to install an English version. 
BTW this question is more suitable for superuser, not stackoverflow.

Comment: That's not true. This is not the *single language edition*, so everything else changed but these minor (but annoying) items. Yes, maybe SU... I'll see if I can request a move.

Comment: I'm not talking about single language edition but about any non-English edition. From my experience switching UI language in these editions still leaves some parts in the "base" language.

Comment: Yes, I think that's what I am hitting. Idea would be to install the correct package that changes the output, or reapply the language changes, taht is made during the OOBX setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **term *alias* in the output from `net localgroup`** is somewhat misleading, as it **simply refers to the *name* of a local group** - see the bottom section for details.

It seems that the following pieces of information are ***statically* assigned based on the Windows display (user-interface) language that the OS *was set up with***:

- The ***names*** of ***built-in* local user and group accounts**, such as `Administrators` (in English) / `Administradores` (in Spanish).
- Their ***descriptions***.

Therefore, **changing the Windows display language *later*** (by installing a *language pack*, as discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77560039/45375) to your linked question) **does *not* change this information, so your only option is to do it yourself** - see next section.

---

In addition to **renaming such accounts and updating their descriptions** being possible *interactively* via `lusrmgr.msc`, you can also do so *programmatically*:

**Caveat:**

- **Renaming user and group accounts can break existing scripts** (unless they happen to use SIDs instead of names).
- It **was an unfortunate design decision on the part of Windows to begin with to localize such names**, precisely because it hampers portability of code between machines that shipped with different display languages or, as in your case, switching to a different display language.

```bash
# Establish a mapping by SID for all built-in *groups*
# to their English names and descriptions.
# See below for how to create this hashtable programmatically.
$sidMap_Groups = 
  [ordered] @{
    'S-1-5-32-544' = [ordered] @{
      Name = 'Administrators'
      Description = 'Administrators have complete and unrestricted access to the computer/domain'
    }
  # ... 
}

# Ditto for built-in *users*, but with keys based on the
# *last SID component* only.
# See below for how to create this hashtable programmatically.
$sidMap_Users = 
  [ordered] @{
    '500' = [ordered] @{
        Name = 'Administrator'
        Description = 'Built-in account for administering the computer/domain'
    }

  # ... 
}

# Rename and update built-in *groups*
Get-LocalGroup | 
  ForEach-Object {
    if ($entry = $sidMap_Groups[$_.SID.Value]) {
       # !! See below for why Set-LocalGroup is *not* an option.
       net localgroup $_.Name /comment:$($entry.Description)
       $_ | Rename-LocalGroup -NewName $entry.Name
    }
  }


# Rename and update built-in *users*
Get-LocalUser | 
  ForEach-Object {
    if ($entry = $sidMap_Users[($_.SID.Value -split '-')[-1]]) {
       # !! See below for why Set-LocalUser is *not* an option.
       net user $_.Name /comment:$($entry.Description)
       $_ | Rename-LocalUser -NewName $entry.Name
    }
  }
```

Note:

- Inexplicably, [`Set-LocalUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/set-localuser) and [`Set-LocalGroup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/set-localgroup), as of version 1.0.0.0 of their enclosing `Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts` module, have a hard *48-character limit* on the value passed to their `-Description` parameter.
- By contrast, `net.exe`, via its `localgroup` and `user` subcommands, does *not* have this limitation with its `/comment` parameter, which is why it is used above.

If you have access to a machine that was set up with English during installation and is currently set up for PowerShell [remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Remote), you can create the `$sidMap_Groups` and `$sidMap_Users` hashtables as follows, assuming `$computer` as that machine's name:

```bash
$sidMap_Groups, $sidMap_Users =
  Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer {
    $sidMap_Groups = [ordered] @{}
    Get-LocalGroup | 
      Where-Object { 
        # Infer whether an account is built-in from the number of SID components.
        ($_.SID.Value -split '-').Count -eq 5 
      } |
      ForEach-Object {
        $sidMap_Groups[$_.SID.Value] = [ordered] @{ Name = $_.Name; Description = $_.Description }
      }

    $sidMap_Users = [ordered] @{}
    Get-LocalUser | 
      Where-Object { 
        # Infer whether an account is built-in from the last SID component.
        [int] ($_.SID.Value -split '-')[-1] -lt 1000
      } |
      ForEach-Object {
        $sidMap_Users[($_.SID.Value -split '-')[-1]] = [ordered] @{ Name = $_.Name; Description = $_.Description }
      }

    $sidMap_Groups, $sidMap_Users
  }
```

---

**Group-related *terminology* in `net localgroup` and `whoami /groups` output**:

In effect, *all local groups* are categorized as ***aliases***, irrespective of whether they are built-in groups (e.g. `Adminstrators`) or not.

Not all built-in groups are represented as local groups, however, namely not those that are purely "virtual" groups whose membership is *inferred* from the membership of other groups (e.g. `Everyone`) and `whoami /groups` calls these ***well-known groups***.

In a wider sense, *both* these subtypes of built-in groups are *well-known*, and they all have *well-known, unchanging [SID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/manage/understand-security-identifiers)s* (Security Identifiers).

Since every concrete user and group account has a name *that can be changed* (including those of *built-in* groups, as happens implicitly during installation of Windows with a language other than English), the *name* of a user or group can be conceived of as a - changeable - *alias* of the user or group's SID, i.e. their - unchanging - identifier.

As for the ***label*** line in the output from `whoami /groups`: This isn't actually related to user groups, but identifies the *integrity level* of the current *process*, in the context of [Mandatory Integrity Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_Integrity_Control): `High Mandatory Level` implies that you've run the command from an *elevated* session; a non-elevated session shows `Medium Mandatory Level`.

Comment: I always learn a lot of new and weird stuff about windows from your answers. TY.